# Should there be a way to flag the 'Edit Summary' text in a post's revision history?

Tags: discussion, edits, flags

Should there be a way to flag the 'Edit Summary' text in a post's revision history? I've seen a few inappropriate comments that don't really need to be there that are a bit churlish and pointless.

Given that we can flag just about everything else this seems to be the last bastion for those that feel they need to pop a vein about another user's question or answer.

Comment: I just flagged Rich B's edit comment ;-)

Comment: @Nathan: Excellent. How difficult was it?

Answer (score 14):

No, just flag the post for moderator review and ask them to check the history with an explanation of what you think is wrong.

For the rare occasions where this could be useful, I don't think it warrants complicating the system further.

Comment: Since the edit notes are in such a remote corner of the site, it would be a waste of the developers' time to add a "flag edit comments" feature.  Just flag.

Comment: @btk: Agreed. Are we going to go and have a flagging function for someone's profile? Their avatar? Their location? Are we in kindergarten?

Comment: God, I should read what I wrote before hitting submit.  When I said "Just flag" I meant just flag the post in question as Rich has suggested.