# How can you flag a commitment comment as offensive?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, flags, commitment-phase

I was wondering if there was a way to flag a Commitment Comment that someone leaves.

Comment: Is there one you have in mind?

Comment: @Dr. Gonzo nope.  I was thinking just in case.

Comment: Ah. Yes, it does appear to missing functionality ...

Comment: I could think of a couple of future candidates...

Comment: That sounds completely reasonable.

Comment: Is this completed?  It was flagged to add the `status-completed` tag, but I can't see a way to flag commitment comments on Area 51.

Comment: You mods and your [insatiable hunger for more flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/should-there-be-a-way-to-flag-the-edit-summary-text-in-a-posts-revision-histo)....

Comment: @PopularDemand Haha, I posted this long before I was a mod.  I guess it was just destiny `:P`

Comment: @PopularDemand And, we want more *valid* flags.

Comment: Oh, I know. Congrats, by the way, if I hadn't said that already. It's nice to see someone I voted for finally get a diamond.