# Changes to edit summaries are turfed with no notice

Tags: feature-request, popups, edit-summary

Problem:

- Make edit
- Realize, later, that you should have added an edit summary and did not (or that you just want to change it).
- Add or change edit summary.
- Press 'Save Edits'.
- Edit summary *is not saved*.

Possible solutions:

1. Make it so that edit summary changes *are* saved (already asked for here: [Editing edit summaries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96918/editing-edit-summaries))
2. Make it clearer when it will not be saved (and give the warning before a user goes to the trouble of typing out a new edit summary).

The way it works now a person could make new edits in order to save a new edit summary, but that should not be required as it just encourages fake edits.

For 2., all that would be needed is an pop-up alert when the user clicks on in the edit summary field without having made any new changes.  Something along the lines of "**This edit summary will not be saved unless new edits to the post are made.**"

---

Here are some more details, in case this is not the way it works all of the time:
I made an edit (actually a roll-back on my own post), but did not know there was a comment field for that.  About an hour later, I found out there was such a thing as an edit summary, so I hit "edit", added one for the roll-back, and pressed "save".  I happened to think I should make sure the edit summary stuck (since I really wanted to make sure the original editor got to read why I did the roll-back) and when I hit "edit" again it turned out that no, it didn't.  The edit summary was gone.

Comment: I think it does work this way all the time. I’ve tried revising my edit summary on two different occasions, but the change was not saved along with my edit. I think I remember this happening even when I changed the body of the edited post along with the edit summary, but [the answer to the question you linked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96935/184047) says the edit should go through in that case.

Comment: So it may be an even bigger problem that I said?  OK, well if it is fixed in the case I mentioned, then I imagine that would fix it for the case you mentioned.