# How to modify the description of an edit?

Tags: support, edit-summary

I edited [a question I posted](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19846/are-liberal-arts-courses-harder-than-those-at-research-universities) to add a long update but forgot to add a description of the edit before hitting 'Save Edits'. In revision view, the edit is described as "added 1232 characters in body". Clicking "edit" for this revision will lead to a new revision which I do not want.

Is there any way to edit the description of a revision?

Comment: There is not, not even [during the grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189031/changes-to-edit-summaries-are-turfed-with-no-notice).

Comment: @MartijnPieters there is a way around though, you need to edit again during the 5 minutes grace period, make another minor change, add the description and it will stick. Then you can remove the minor change (yes, third edit) and all is done. Ugly, but working.