# If the revision comment is the One Long Word, it doesn't wrap... or do anything else not to look that long

Tags: bug, status-declined, revisions-list

[Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/258889/revisions):[image]

Also, it causes the revision number to have no right margin.

It probably should be wrapped.

Comment: Ugh, why the normal screenshot looks so garbadged on imgur?

Comment: How about, instead, people who consistently leave useless edit summary comments spend a little time in the penalty box?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What @FishBelowtheIce said. There's absolutely no reason to waste dev time on people abusing their privileges like that. Far simpler to just suspend the culprit and move on.

Comment: @Fish Lolwtf? Consistently, seriously? No. Also, a revision summary is not a reason to get suspended :/

Comment: Again, absolutely unrelated, @Yannis. It is a bug.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​@nicael No it is not. You are supposed to write something _helpful_ in the revision summary, and if you use the feature as intended everything works fine. If, on the other hand, you are abusing the feature to post something completely moronic like in your example, then who cares?

Comment: @Yannis I can't think of a normal word of that length right now, but surely you'll find some in German ;)

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft. Still, not long enough for your "bug" to appear.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/should-there-be-a-way-to-flag-the-edit-summary-text-in-a-posts-revision-histo

Comment: What are you talking about? Users get suspended for being unremitting jerks all the time

Comment: Well, the community seems to have decided that this is a non-issue (just like most of the others).

Comment: @san Wait, really? And I thought downvotes indicate absolute agreement... :D maybe stop playing Captain Obvious finally xd

Comment: No need to be rude

Comment: @san I wasn't :) You are just saying waaay to obvious things.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[SMITH: Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*.

DALE: Don't *do* that.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_%26_Dale#.22Dr._Kronkheit_and_His_Only_Living_Patient.22)

Comment: Quite of an idea. But it is a bug anyway :D

Comment: And btw, you seem to have fallen in love with these words :)

Comment: It's more that I've never before had so many opportunities to use them.

Comment: And now that you use SE you do? :D I love them too, anyway. Who would think they are so applicable there?

Comment: This is a trivial bug that is not an issue in practice. The only time it will be an issue is if someone deliberately does something that makes no sense under normal circumstances... which is potentially suspension-worthy as Yannis said in comments.

Comment: Hey no! Find a single revision longer than that in my rev history. I couldn't honestly resist to *test* it, but don't abuse it *always*...

Comment: Chill. I said "potentially". Talking in general here, not about you specifically.