# Revision history comments may not wrap if they are very long

Tags: bug, revisions-list

If the comment in the revision history is very long, the text may cover the editor's information without wrapping in some cases.

This issue mainly occurs only in Chromium-based browsers. (Chrome, Opera, Edge)

e.g.
https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3502/revisions

[image]

I found a similar declined post, but this time I think the problem is that the editor's information is overwhelmed by the text.

Related:
[If the revision comment is the One Long Word, it doesn't wrap… or do anything else not to look that long](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258915)