# What should reviewers do with otherwise good edit suggestions that have offensive summary comments?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I just ran into [this Suggested Edits review item](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/515649). The changes made are good, I would like to use Improve Edit to polish it a little more. What makes this item special is that the edit comment definitely falls under "rude or offensive." If I approved or improved that edit, the summary comment would require a custom moderator flag to remove, and that would be unfortunate.

Since this specific edit was proposed an anonymous user (with no rep on the line), I copy-pasted the revised Markdown from the *Improve Edit* box to the *Reject and Edit* one, causing the edit to be unilaterally rejected. Is that always the right thing to do?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18110/should-there-be-a-way-to-flag-the-edit-summary-text-in-a-posts-revision-histo

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59597/allow-mods-to-edit-revision-comments

Answer (score 3):

I would just reject the edit with the *causes harm* reason and explain why you rejected the edit.

The problem with this is though that moderators will never see this and they can't see pattern with abusive users if we keep just rejecting them. Possibly a flag would be warranted anyways, depending on the degree of rudeness in the edit comment.

Answer (score 2):

If the edit is good, you should accept it. Once the edit is applied, flag the post for moderator attention and explain that the revision summary is abusive. The moderator who reviews the flag will be able to edit the revision summary to something more acceptable.

This way, the post gets the necessary improvements, and we aren't stuck with an inappropriate revision summary for too long.